# Why is my css not working on v-checkbox's icon?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have two icons and I'm trying to customize them

```
<v-checbkox icon class="icons" off-icon="mdi-close" on-icon="mdi-mark"></v-checkbox>
```

I want something like this :

[image]

And actually I have this :

[image]

I tried this (got it from css dev mode of the first icon)  :

```
.icons {
    background-color: red;
    color:green !important;
    font-weight: 200;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

And the `font-weight` doesn't change, the `color` don't change the icon but the hover color and the `background color` is a (way) too big square.

What I am doing wrong?

**Update**

`Background-color` gaves me this :

[image]

Ok this almost worked :

```
    <v-checkbox
      v-model="answer.correct"
      on-icon="mdi-check"
      off-icon="mdi-close"
      color="white"
      style="border-radius:6px; width:40px; height:40px"
      :class="{ 'success': answer.correct, 'red': !answer.correct}"
      class="answer-toggle icons mr-3 pl-2 pt-2"
    ></v-checkbox>
```

[image]

But the white only works for `mdi-check` not `mdi-close`

How can I give it the same condition as the class and make the icon larger.

Comment: Inspect & check if the "checkbox" has the icons class.

Comment: @NiceBooks yes it has

Comment: I'm not sure if both :class & class can be used on the same Vue element. Better to merge it into a single prop like `:class={cls1: cond1, cls2: true }`

Answer (score 2):

It seems to change color & background-color, you should use the corresponding `v-checkbox` props.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-checkbox/#props

Comment: I edited my question ! so you can see the results

Answer (score 2):

As per the [Vuetify docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/checkboxes/#props) you can change the checkbox's appearance by settings its props like the following (I've used the colour picker to match your example)

```
<v-checkbox
    v-model="your-model"
    label="success"
    color="#377d22"
    value="success"
    hide-details
></v-checkbox>
```

Comment: I edited my question ! so you can see the results

Comment: Have you tried adding `color="success"` to your checkboxes props?

Comment: Yes it changes the color but I want exactly the same thing as the first image. A green background with a white button.

Comment: What about if you remove the custom CSS that you added?

Comment: You can see my update, it almost worked.

Comment: When your checkbox is unchecked, inspect it and show us what's in the `red` class. There should hopefully be a colour set there that you can update

Answer (score 0):

You probably already solved this, but gonna answer here in case this can help anyone.
Instead of using the 'mdi-check' and 'mdi-close' you should be using:

```
<v-checkbox
  v-model="answer.correct"
  on-icon="mdi-checkbox-marked"
  off-icon="mdi-close-box"
  :color="answer.correct ? 'green' : 'red'"
></v-checkbox>
```

These icons already have the box, so you don't have to create a box around your icons.
And set the color according to you logic.
For more icons: https://materialdesignicons.com/